# Using I18n for displaying details such as name and description in different languages. Using v-for to loop through json file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, v-for, vue-i18n

I am having problems to display the details in different languages from the Json file which I am looping using v-for. It's only displaying it in the language I choose. it won't display the translated content in other languages if I toggle the language options on the webpage.

> 

```
    <div class="artist_grid_list_container">
          <ul class="artist_grid_list" v-show="profile_flag">
                <li class="artist_grid_list_item" v-for="item in data.en" :key="item.id">
                    <span class="artist_grid_list_item_box"
                      ><img
                        v-on:click="modal_on('naritaaiko')"
                        :src="item.img"
                        data-micromodal-trigger="modal-1"
                        class="modal_open"
                    /></span>
                    <p class="member_name">{{item.artist_name}}</p>
                </li>
```

The

tag with a class "member_name" is just deplaying the json with the en details, if I type ja or cn instead of en it will switch. My point is I dont want it to be displaying this way. I want to use the I18n to be able to automatically switch language by choosing it on the webpage.

Here's the json file code:

> 

```
{
"en":
    [{
      "img":"/img/event/cheersupports/2022/appreciation/profile/naritaaiko_hyakka.jpg",
      "artist_name": "Narita Aiko and Hyakka-Ryouran",
      "artist_profile":  "She is active in a band mainly in Yokohama.<br>She is a singer who sends various messages through her songs, and also throws out inspirational messages.<br>Especially, she sings nostalgic melodies, Hawaiian music, movie music, and songs, especially Hibari Misora.<br>While volunteering at nursing homes and other facilities, she aims to create a band that can push people to dream and hope."
  },
  {
      "img":"/img/event/cheersupports/2022/appreciation/profile/ko_ryudai.jpg",
      "artist_name": "Ko Ryudai",
      "artist_profile":  "Japanese drum and shinobue player<br>Born in Beppu City, Oita Prefecture.<br>After graduating from high school, he joined a professional Japanese instrument group.<br>He has toured in France, Germany, Russia, and the United States as a performer.<br>In Japan, he performed in the Kohaku Uta Gassen (Red and White Singing Contest).<br>He has traveled around the world with various Japanese instruments such as taiko, koto, and shinobue.<br>After leaving a professional taiko group in 2019, he will be a solo artist to promote the appeal of Japanese instruments."
  },
  {
```

I have the same text for JN and CN languages. Just showing how the json file is structured.

This is what I have in the script which allows for localization.

> 

```
var i18njs = require("~/locale/i18n.js");
var i18n = i18njs.selectLocale("event/cheerssupports/2022/appreciation/profile");
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

I tried different options but none work such as changing the following code:

I changed the json file and removed the en/jn/cn code and instead I typed them as an extension on each key value pairs.

```
"artist_name_en": ,
      "artist_profile_en": 
  },
```

Then changing the code:

> 

```
<div v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
     <p {{item.artist_name_[$i18n.locale]}} </p>
</div>
```

this didn't work as well.

I don't want to hard code all the HTML for this. I want to make the code simpler using javasscript and i18n...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your `i18n` but I use [`i18next`](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/objects-and-arrays).

Then anywhere you have anything which is translated, you have to render your page in the javascript, something like

```
html = `<div>${i18n.t('data.0.artist_name')}</div>
<dib>${i18n.t('data.0.artist_profile')}</div>`;
```

Then to change languages you need to run

```
i18n.changeLanguage('en');  # or jp/cn/etc
```

and then you need to reload all the html which uses translations. `i18n` will automatically choose the current language for you.

How this works for your specific case I don't know, maybe you can init the `i18next` object and tell it where the translations are. For me I have all the translations as objects and access them with `i18n.t` dot notation (no 0), but I think what I showed above is how you access arrays, you can try it out. You could try initializing the i18n object like this:

```
i18n = i18next
.init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lng: 'en',
    resources: {
        en: {
            translation: en,
        },
        jp: {
            translation: jp,
        },
        cn: {
            translation: cn,
        },
    },
});
```

where en, jp and cn are the objects with translations.

Another thing you can do to switch languages if you prefer is you can refresh the page and pass in a query parameter, e.g. `website.com?lang=cn` and have your website load the proper `i18n` translations.

Comment: Thank you I finally found a solution I just had to add language as a prop. The prop was definied in i18n.js

Comment: perfect, you can add your solution as an answer so it may help someone else

Comment: I just used lang as a prop and so if the language option changes, it will loop the data in that language only. Here's the code: <li class ="artist_grid_list_item" v for="item in data[lang]" key="item.id" data-toggle="modal_container" data_target="appreciationModal" @click="sendInfo(item)">